# Horizontal line on top of the display

Tags: macbook-pro

Whenever i turn my laptop on, after using for 15-20mins/ half an hour the horizontal line on the top of the display showed itself, and vibrate continuously. It get bigger in width slowly.

if i put it to sleep for 5mins and open again, everything look likes okey. but after around 15mins again that line blow up

help me if there is any solution. isn’t there any solution without replacing display?

i have no warrenty left from apple

Macbook Pro 13” 2017

[image]

Comment: That looks an awfully lot like an issue with the GPU or the LCD. Not software and it would involve replacing expen$sive  parts...

Comment: Firstly, welcome to Ask Different! :)  Even though your standard Apple warranty is over you *may* have consumer laws in your country that would mean you'd still be eligible for service, so that's something worth investigating. In addition, I'd actually try connecting your MBP to an external display to test to see if the problem repeats itself there. If it does, then you know it's the GPU, and if it doesn't then it could be the internal screen or the cable. Regardless, waiting it out may work in your favour - if it ends up being a known issue, Apple is likely to start a repair program for it.